# When I try changing the color of my border radius it doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm just wondering why the color of my border radius isn't changing, can someone please answer my question?

Code:

```
* {
  font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: url('http://clubpenguincode.com/other/background.png'); 
} 

.header {
  background-color: #008aff;
  height: 72px;
  width: 700px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ff0000 #0000ff;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `border-radius` property refers to the radius of the corners of the element. I believe your mistake is that you have mistaken this property as the size of your border.

If you have a certain element such as `<div class="my-element"></div>` and you want to give it a colored border, the proper CSS is as follows:

```
.my-element {
    /* border: [style] [size] [color] */
    border: solid 1px #FFF;

    /* or individually */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #FFF;
}
```

Furthermore, to round this element, you must add a `border-radius` rule that supports all the various CSS3 browser vendors (to make this work in all/most modern browsers):

```
.my-element {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

set `border-width`

```
.header {
    background-color: #008aff;
    height: 72px;
    width: 700px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ff0000 #0000ff;
    border-width:5px;  <-- change the value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a border width:

```
border-width: 1px;
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `-webkit-` just before the border radius.

Comment: Solves nothing, you should try that first.

Answer (score 0):

You want to try to change a color of zero-width border. First, you need to declare `border-width` (now you modify the `border: 0`).

Just add this to `.header`

```
border-width: 3px; /* select the width of blue-red border */
```

Answer (score 0):

`border-width` is not set, this means you can not see the color.

Answer (score -1):

try this.,

```
.header {
      background-color: #008aff;
      height: 72px;
      width: 700px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 2px solid;/* add width size here */
      border-color: #ff0000 #0000ff;
    }
```